# Java - Printing occurrences of a number without duplicating

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to display the following after prompting users for input:

[image]

Whereas this is my current input:

[image]

As you can see, if I input a number twice, it is listed twice.

Any suggestions on what to do? This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList<Integer> Digits = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.print("Enter digits: ");
    int value;

    do {
        value = input.nextInt();
        if (value > 1 && value < 101) 
            Digits.add(value);
        } while (value != 0);

    java.util.Collections.sort(Digits);
    Set<Integer> uniqueInputs = new HashSet<Integer>(Digits);
    for (int i = 0; i < Digits.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(Digits.get(i) + " - " + Collections.frequency(Digits, Digits.get(i)) + " times");
    }
```

Comment: You're almost there. You already have `uniqueInputs` (currently never used). Now you just need to iterate over it and get frequencies of it's elements in the original List.

Comment: When reading digits you exclude `1` change the check to `value >= 1`

Answer (score 1):

you are done, only change the printing section

````
ArrayList<Integer> Digits = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 2, 3,2));
java.util.Collections.sort(Digits);
Set<Integer> uniqueInputs = new HashSet<>(Digits);

// printing
uniqueInputs.forEach(digit-> System.out.println(digit + " - " + Collections.frequency(Digits, digit) + " times"));```
````

Answer (score 1):

A good way to approach it would be a `SortedMap`. It will make your code simpler and enhance performance. You would avoid additional collections and operations as follows:

```
SortedMap<Integer, Integer> numbers = new TreeMap<>();
int value;

do {
    value = input.nextInt();
    if (value > 1 && value < 101) {
        numbers.put(value, numbers.getOrDefault(value, 0) + 1);
    }
} while (value != 0);

for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> number : numbers.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(number.getKey() + " - " + number.getValue() + " times");
}
```

**UNRELATED:** by convention in Java variable names are lower camel case.

Comment: Your solution also worked perfectly, other than that the output ignores 1's. Any idea why?

Comment: Just saw my mistake! I put value > 1 instead of value > 0.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a set of unique digits as not to repeat calculations multiple times. Then calculate frequencies for each of them and put results in a Map. Then print out the results.

```java
List<Integer> digits = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 2, 3, 2);

Set<Integer> uniqueDigits = new HashSet<Integer>(digits);
Map<Integer, Integer> frequencies = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
uniqueDigits.forEach(uniqueDigit -> frequencies.put(uniqueDigit, Collections.frequency(digits, uniqueDigit)));

// Printing
frequencies.keySet().forEach(key -> System.out.println(key + " - " + frequencies.get(key) + " times"));
```

Comment: Thank you tons! This worked, except for that it for some reason ignores 1's in the output... Any idea why?

Comment: Just saw my mistake! I put value > 1 instead of value > 0.